# Button image not shown correctly for retina display

Tags: uibutton, retina

I have a button image, which gets set properly if called from interface builder. But when set from code image not shown correctly for retina display. 
Do I have to explicitly specify for 2x images in code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two PNG images, lets say

```
CoolImage.png
```

and

```
CoolImage@2x.png
```

then you simply call the following:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"CoolImage"]
```

and everything will work as you expect.

Comment: Is it required that the 2x image be of the exact double size of normal image?

Comment: Thanks everyone.The issue was with image size. The 2x image wasn't double of the normal image.